# R.Swift with SPM setup error SourcePackages/checkouts/R.swift/rswift: No such file or directory

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, xcode13, r.swift

Receiving this error:

```
/SourcePackages/checkouts/R.swift/rswift: No such file or directory
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Use SPM for installation and this run code in Build Phases

```
"${BUILD_DIR%Build/*}/SourcePackages/checkouts/R.swift/rswift" generate --disable-input-output-files-validation "$SRCROOT/NameProj/Resources/R.generated.swift"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you won't be able to use `R.swift` with spm. If you want it to be a dependency do try adding it via pods. Any other way will require you to add R.swift binary manually into the project.

Reference: https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift

Comment: Why I'm won't be able to use R.swift with spm? They are have in manual ability to use SPM

Comment: by manual they mean to download the binary and use it if I'm not wrong.